# Azure Powershell Container Creation - error message

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I'm trying to create a storage container to hold a blob image in MS Azure. I am using the Azure Powershell.

I created a resource group and a storage account and I have run these commands:

`$blobStorageAccountKey = ((Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName cloud-shell-storage-westeurope -Name "robStorageAccount")| Where-Object {$_.KeyName -eq "key1"}).Value`

`$blobStorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "robStorageAccount" -StorageAccountKey $blobStorageAccountKey`

But when I run this command I receive the error below:

`New-AzStorageContainer -Name images -Context $blobStorageContext`

```
    New-AzStorageContainer: One of the request inputs is out of range.                                                      
    RequestId:9b0b4ec8-801e-004c-3e02-eaedfa000000                                                                          
    Time:2022-10-27T12:52:06.5326241Z                                                                                       
    Status: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.)                                                                
    ErrorCode: OutOfRangeInput                                                                                              
    Content:                                                                                                                
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>OutOfRangeInput</Code><Message>One of the request inputs is out of range.
    RequestId:9b0b4ec8-801e-004c-3e02-eaedfa000000                                                                          
    Time:2022-10-27T12:52:06.5326241Z</Message></Error>                                                                     
    Headers:                                                                                                                
    Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0                                                                                           
    x-ms-request-id: 9b0b4ec8-801e-004c-3e02-eaedfa000000                                                                   
    x-ms-error-code: OutOfRangeInput                                                                                        
    Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2022 12:52:05 GMT                                                                                     
    Content-Length: 226                                                                                                     
    Content-Type: application/xml
```

Any ideas on what to check here and any useful azure powershell commands to run?

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and created container successfully by using below commands:***

```bash
$storageAccoun= Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName testruk -Name StorageAccName

$CTX = $storageAccoun.Context

New-AzStorageContainer -Name ContainerName -Context $ctx -Permission blob
```

[image]

[image]

**In the Portal, Container is successfully created like below**:

[image]